# Compute Engine Free Tier

Tags: google-compute-engine

Here's what's said about Google Compute Engine free tier [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier/)

[image]

But in the Google Cloud Pricing Calculator I don't see anything what says about free tier when adding an estimate for an instance with such parameters:

[image]

So is there any *real* free tier for Compute Engine or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven't updated their calculator, if you pick their older f1-micro you'll see a checkbox to "Include Always Free usage in my estimate." The f1-micro is no longer free since August 31st, 2021, and the e2-micro free tier was introduced on August 1st, 2021.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the free tier is as you posted for compute engine. That is the cost for that particular setup, however your free tier credits will be deducted from that price so you will end up paying nothing. Note do not set it to 30GB when creating your disk, set it a bit less, like 28GB to avoid getting charged. Also note that static IP address are not included in the free tier.

Comment: Do you mean free trial credits by "free tier credits"?. I mean I don't quite understand what this means: "your free tier credits will be deducted from that price"

Comment: no I did not mean free trail credits